# JavaScript: Accessing objects in different classes

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have:

```
View1.prototype.function1 = function() {
    this.test = "Hello";
};
```

And I want to call test in here:

```
View2.prototype.funcion2 = function() {
   alert(View1.test);
};
```

However I get can error that View1 does not exist.

Ideas?

Comment: You need to instantiate a `View1`. For example, `var view = new View1(); alert(view.test);`.

Comment: Is there another solution that does not involve instantiating View1?

Comment: You've designed it so that you need to do so, since each instance of `View1` would have its own instance of `test`. You could just have `View1.test = "Hello";`.

Comment: @WaleedKhan +1, although you'd also need to call `view.function1()`. Or perhaps this can be done inside the `View1()` constructor.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: I think you were looking for `alert(this.test)` it would make more sense.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do, the following may help (or not).

It's a convention in ECMAScript that variable names starting with a capital letter are constructors, e.g.

```
function View() {
  ...
}
```

To add a method to the constructor that is shared by all instances created from it, assign a function to the constructor's prototype:

```
View.prototype.f1 = function() {
    this.test = "Hello";
};
```

Now to create an instance:

```
var view1 = new View();
```

and call the method:

```
view1.f1();
```

This calls *View.prototype.f1* and passes *view1* as its *this* value, so a *test* property is added with a value of "Hello":

```
alert(view1.test); // Hello
```

You can't call *test* since it's value is a string, and a string isn't callable. Only objects that implement the internal `[[Call]]` method, such as functions or host methods, are callable.

You may be struggling with prototype inheritance. If so, ask here. There are many articles on the web that attempt to explain it, but most are pretty awful.

PS: Firefox doesn't seem to like "function1" as an identifier.

Comment: Thanks this helped me narrow down my problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
View1.prototype.function1.call(View1);

View2.prototype.function2 = function() {
  alert(View1.test);
};
```

Or change `View1` to an object.

Comment: What if `var View1 = function() { };` is being used? I meant as in `var View1 = { test: 'Hello' };`

Comment: I just wanted to clarify that function *is* an object